I got some error in pagination in ci3 below i have attached the error
this is the error
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192
Message: ctype_digit(): Argument of type null will be interpreted as string in the future
Filename: libraries/Pagination.php
Line Number: 526
Backtrace:
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_pagination\application\controllers\country.php
Line: 25
Function: create_links
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_pagination\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
controller
country.php
<?php

    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    
    class country extends CI_Controller {
        
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $this->load->database(); 
            $this->load->model('country_model');
        }
        
        public function index() {
            $config = array();
            $config["base_url"] = site_url("country/index");
            $config["total_rows"] = $this->country_model->record_count();
            $config["per_page"] = 3;
            $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    
            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
            $data["countries"] = $this->country_model->fetch_countries($config["per_page"], $page);
            $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    
            $this->load->view('country_list', $data);
        }
}


It is a known issue with PHP 8+ versions.
Someone mentioned a possible solution until the official staff solves it in the next release:
Change the 518 line of code in system/libraries/Pagination.php, make a type casting on the $this->cur_page variable to string:
From:
if ( ! ctype_digit($this->cur_page) OR ($this->use_page_numbers && (int) $this->cur_page === 0))
to:
if ( ! ctype_digit((string) $this->cur_page) OR ($this->use_page_numbers && (int) $this->cur_page === 0))
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/3e5d10956b0b34c248b388a98b9cf41739dc5c2c
